# Stored procedure to generate HTML response doesnot work

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis

I am trying to get the HTML out from the stored Procedure so I can use this stored procedure in my SSIS package to send email with this body.

This is the SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    cus.CustomerNumber AS CustomerNumber,
    cus.Location AS ReceivingLocation, 
    i.StrainName AS StrainName, i.StrainCode AS StrainCode,
    i.Age AS Age, i.Sex AS Sex, 
    i.Genotype AS Genotype, i.RoomNumber AS SentFrom,
    io.OrderQuantity AS OrderQuantity
FROM 
    [dbo].[MouseOrder] mo
JOIN 
    [dbo].[Customer] cus ON cus.Customer_ID = mo.CustomerId
JOIN 
    [dbo].[InventoryOrder] io ON io.OrderId = mo.MouseOrder_ID
JOIN 
    [dbo].[Inventory] i ON i.Inventory_ID =  io.InventoryId 
WHERE 
    mo.OrderDate = CONVERT(date, GETDATE() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time') 
    AND mo.SAMAccountEmail = 'abc.def@inc.org'
```

Which I tried to do as a stored procedure so it can generate the HTML response

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GenerateEmailBody
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @xhtmlBody XML,
            @body NVARCHAR(MAX),
            @tableCaption VARCHAR(30) = 'Orderlist';

    SET @xhtmlBody = (SELECT (
SELECT cus.CustomerNumber as CustomerNumber,cus.Location as ReceivingLocation, 
       i.StrainName as StrainName,i.StrainCode as StrainCode,i.Age as Age,
       i.Sex as Sex,i.Genotype as Genotype,i.RoomNumber as SentFrom,io.OrderQuantity as OrderQuantity
FROM [dbo].[MouseOrder] mo
JOIN [dbo].[Customer] cus on cus.Customer_ID = mo.CustomerId
JOIN [dbo].[InventoryOrder] io on io.OrderId = mo.MouseOrder_ID
JOIN [dbo].[Inventory] i on i.Inventory_ID =  io.InventoryId 
WHERE mo.OrderDate = convert(date,getdate() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time') and mo.SAMAccountEmail = 'abc.def@inc.org'
FOR XML PATH('row'), TYPE, ROOT('root'))
.query('<html><head>
            <meta charset="utf-8"/>
            (: including embedded CSS styling :)
            <style>
            table <![CDATA[ {border-collapse: collapse;  width: 300px;} ]]>
            th <![CDATA[ {background-color: #4CAF50; color: white;} ]]>
            th, td <![CDATA[ { text-align: left; padding: 8px;} ]]>
            tr:nth-child(even) <![CDATA[ {background-color: #f2f2f2;} ]]>
            #green <![CDATA[ {background-color: lightgreen;} ]]>
         </style>
         </head>
         <body>
<table border="1">
   <caption><h2>{sql:variable("@tableCaption")}</h2></caption>
   <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Cust Numb</th>
        <th>Rec Location</th>
        <th>Strain</th>
        <th>Strain Code</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Sex</th>
        <th>Genotype</th>
        <th>Sent From</th>
        <th>Order Quantity</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
{
    for $row in /root/row
    return <tr>
            <td>{data($row/CustomerNumber)}</td>
            <td>{data($row/ReceivingLocation)}</td>
            <td>{data($row/StrainName)}</td>
            <td>{data($row/StrainCode)}</td>
            <td>{data($row/Age)}</td>
            <td>{data($row/Sex)}</td>
            <td>{data($row/Genotype)}</td>
            <td>{data($row/SentFrom)}</td>
            <td>{data($row/OrderQuantity)}</td>
        </tr>
}
</tbody></table></body></html>'));

SELECT @xhtmlBody;

SET @body = CAST(@xhtmlBody AS NVARCHAR(MAX));
END
GO
```

When I tried to execute the stored procedure, it returns the int as shown here:

[image]

This is my first stored procedure attempt - I'm not sure what I am missing - any help is greatly appreciated

****** EDIT ******

The Execute SQL Task

[image]

[image]

[image]

The Scipt is like below

```
namespace ST_c2e68b3edd6842c4a6554376987c97c1
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {

        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        }

        public void Main()
        {
            string data = Dts.Variables["User::EmailData"].Value.ToString();
            SendEmail(data);
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }

        private void SendEmail(string messageBody)
        {
            ConnectionManager smtpConnectionManager = Dts.Connections["SMTP Connection Manager"];
            SmtpClient emailClient = new SmtpClient(smtpConnectionManager.Properties["SmtpServer"].GetValue(smtpConnectionManager).ToString());

            MailMessage email = new MailMessage();
            email.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;
            email.IsBodyHtml = true; 
            email.From = new MailAddress("abc.def@inc.org");
            email.To.Add("abc.def@inc.org"); 
            email.Body = messageBody;
            emailClient.Send(email);
  }    }}
```

It throws error like

`Error: 0xC002F210 at Execute SQL Task, Execute SQL Task: Executing the query "EXEC dbo.GenerateEmailBody ?" failed with the following error: "Parameter name is unrecognized.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly. Task failed: Execute SQL Task`

Comment: That is because a stored procedure will only return an integer. It is used to indicate the status of the execution. You would need to use an OUTPUT parameter to hold the data like you are trying here.

Comment: Your stored procedure is working.  You need to launch as follows: `EXEC dbo.GenerateEmailBody`

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky How would I parameterize this mo.SAMAccountEmail in the where clause so I can pass the values dynamically to the SP

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want `@body`, you could make that an output parameter:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GenerateEmailBody (@body NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @xhtmlBody XML
      , @tableCaption VARCHAR(30) = 'Orderlist';
...
```

and then call it like:

```
DECLARE @return_value int
DECLARE @html NVARCHAR(MAX)

exec @return_value = [dbo].[GenerateEmailBody] @html OUTPUT
select @html
```

Answer (score 0):

Like below:

**SQL**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_GenerateEmailBody
(
   @SAMAccountEmail VARCHAR(100)
)
AS
BEGIN
...
... and mo.SAMAccountEmail = @SAMAccountEmail -- usage of the SP parameter
```

Comment: I really appreciate your patience in helping me get this thing working.. Thanks a ton.. I am again stuck.. I have edited the question where it is failing now

Comment: @I am sorry, I am unable to connect as I am in office