# SSIS Script Task to send email doesnot show the data correctly

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ssis, etl

I am trying to query the database and send the content in the body of the email. The content is Order and the details for each users. I am trying to call a script task to compose the body and I am using the content in the Send Email Task. When I try to run the package it executes without error but below I what I am seeing in my email

```
Execute SQL task output sent using Send Email Task in SSIS:

Customer Num    Rec Loc Strain  StrainCode  Age Sex Genotype    Sent From   Quantity
Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Variable    Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Variable    Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Variable    Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Variable    Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Variable    Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Variable    Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Variable    Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Variable    Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Variable
```

Below is the script

```
namespace ST_c074d0acfee7488b96d42a0f858efee7
{
       [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
        public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
        {

            #region VSTA generated code
            enum ScriptResults
            {
                Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
                Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
            };
            #endregion

            public void Main()
            {
                string header = string.Empty;
                string message = string.Empty;

                header = "Execute SQL task output sent using Send Email Task in SSIS:\n\n";
                header += string.Format("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}\t{5}\t{6}\t{7}\t{8}\n", "Customer Num", "Rec Loc", "Strain", "StrainCode", "Age", "Sex", "Genotype", "Sent From", "Quantity");
                message = string.Format("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}\t{5}\t{6}\t{7}\t{8}",
                                            Dts.Variables["User::CustomerNumber"].ToString(),
                                            Dts.Variables["User::ReceivingLocation"].ToString(),
                                            Dts.Variables["User::StrainName"].ToString(),
                                            Dts.Variables["User::StrainCode"].ToString(),
                                            Dts.Variables["User::Age"].ToString(),
                                            Dts.Variables["User::Sex"].ToString(),
                                            Dts.Variables["User::Genotype"].ToString(),
                                            Dts.Variables["User::SentFrom"].ToString(),
                                            Dts.Variables["User::OrderQuantity"].ToString());

            Dts.Variables["User::EmailMessage"].Value= header + message;

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
            }
        }
    }
```

Below is the package

[image]

And to the Script Task properties I am passing all the required data like below

[image]

and the Query to get all the data

[image]

And the For loop I am doing the mapping

[image]

Can anyone please suggest me what is that I am missing here and why my email shows no real data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue I had to do

```
 Dts.Variables["User::Age"].Value.ToString(),
```

Instead of

```
Dts.Variables["User::Age"].ToString(),
```